# Email into database

Tags: database, email

I am wondering if it is possible to insert info into a database using email? I am thinking of like how Youtube or Blogger uses this, where you can email posts or videos into your account. I am just wondering if this is easy enough for a slight n00b like myself or if you guys have a good link.

Comment: please state whaat mail server you are running

Answer (score 2):

http://www.codefixer.com/tutorials/form_to_database.asp Hope this helps!
Please vote on it if it does

Comment: Should it?  That appears to be about how to insert things into databases from *forms*, not email.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly. You have a variety of options, not the least of which are autoresponders and something to run on a cron job. The first would be called by the system when mail arrives for the target account; this kind of thing is generally an option (usually free) with most hosting accounts. You don't *have* to use it to reply to clients with spam - you can instead write appropriate code to handle attachments, etc., and populate your database, fax resignation letters to rivals' bosses, start your coffeepot, anything.

The second, you'd write a small program that would be run at some designated interval, check the mail, then handle it however.

Answer (score 0):

The way this would generally work, is you would have an application which fetches the emails from a mailbox ( or accepts them directly ), processes that email, then inserts into the database. You can't email directly into a database ( it doesn't know what to do with it ).

Answer (score 0):

You might consider writing a custom exim handler (or handler for some other mail server) that calls an external script, at which point you can write database insert code any way you choose.  Exim's `$(run ...)` expansion is probably the one you want:

http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch11.html

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.  What you'd have to do is develop a client application to be checking the email from an SMTP server and a given address.  Then the application could parse the text in the email (to ensure that it is indeed valid SQL), and if that succeeds execute the dynamic SQL against the database.

You can get very creative with this, but there are definitely **HUGE** security risks unless you limit the sender that can write these email queries.